# How to correctly toggle updates on my Java GUI (Lanterna)

Tags: java, user-interface, lanterna

I'm currently writing a GUI using the [Lanterna](https://github.com/mabe02/lanterna) library. Currently, I'm developing a GUI which must contain several components that display info of a given type `Note`. The code renders the GUI, but, the `removeNoteFromList` method doesn't seem to be working. I'm currently trying to use the `invalidate` method for the panels that might need to be redrawn, but nothing is really happening. Can I get some advice on how to solve it?

Here's the Code responsible for the drawing.

**EDIT:** I updated the code a little bit. Now the user interface gets updated, but after the update, the GUI just freezes, and I cannot move the cursor or do anything else inside it

```java
package com.github.gtvb.stns.application.gui.notesList;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

import com.github.gtvb.stns.domain.model.Note;
import com.googlecode.lanterna.gui2.BasicWindow;
import com.googlecode.lanterna.gui2.Button;
import com.googlecode.lanterna.gui2.Direction;
import com.googlecode.lanterna.gui2.GridLayout;
import com.googlecode.lanterna.gui2.Label;
import com.googlecode.lanterna.gui2.LinearLayout;
import com.googlecode.lanterna.gui2.Panel;
import com.googlecode.lanterna.gui2.TextBox;
import com.googlecode.lanterna.gui2.dialogs.MessageDialog;

public class NotesListWindow extends BasicWindow {
    private ArrayList<Note> notes;
    private Panel notesPanel;

    public NotesListWindow(ArrayList<Note> notes) {
        this.notes = notes;

        Panel mainPanel = new Panel();
        mainPanel.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayout(Direction.VERTICAL));

        notesPanel = new Panel();
        notesPanel.setLayoutManager(new GridLayout(2).setHorizontalSpacing(5));

        refreshNotesPanel();

        mainPanel.addComponent(notesPanel);
        setComponent(mainPanel);
    }

    private void refreshNotesPanel() {
        notesPanel.removeAllComponents(); // Clear the panel

        for (Note note : notes) {
            Panel notePanel = createNotePanel(note);
            notesPanel.addComponent(notePanel);
        }
    }

    private Panel createNotePanel(Note note) {
        Panel panel = new Panel();
        panel.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayout(Direction.VERTICAL));

        panel.addComponent(new Label(note.getCreatedAt()));
        panel.addComponent(new Label(note.getTitle()));

        TextBox contentsTextBox = new TextBox(note.getContents())
                .setLayoutData(LinearLayout.createLayoutData(LinearLayout.Alignment.Fill));
        panel.addComponent(contentsTextBox);

        Button removeButton = new Button("Remove", new RemoveButtonAction(note));
        panel.addComponent(removeButton);

        Button saveButton = new Button("Save", new SaveButtonAction(note, contentsTextBox));
        panel.addComponent(saveButton);

        return panel;
    }

    private class RemoveButtonAction implements Runnable {
        private Note note;

        public RemoveButtonAction(Note note) {
            this.note = note;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
             notes.remove(note);
             refreshNotesPanel();
        }
    }

    private class SaveButtonAction implements Runnable {
        private Note note;
        private TextBox contentsTextBox;

        public SaveButtonAction(Note note, TextBox contentsTextBox) {
            this.note = note;
            this.contentsTextBox = contentsTextBox;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            String newContents = contentsTextBox.getText();
            note.setContents(newContents);

            // Perform any additional saving operations here
            MessageDialog.showMessageDialog(getTextGUI(), "Note Saved", "Contents saved successfully!");
            refreshNotesPanel();
        }
    }
}
```